# ANGULAR ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Here is my problem and I do not know if it is a conflict between angular and jQuery.

if I use the script

```js
$ ("select"). selecter ()
```

to my style, all values in my "optionSelect" are empty set, and if I comment the script, I get the values.
Are you a solution to this conflict?
with the script :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select . It's angular js directive for select.

Comment: Using the ui-select, I a problem on a ng-click when clicking on the small down arrow that this one will refresh my page every click.
Is it not possible to use the ng options and remove the conflict with jQuery?
Thank you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview check this out please. Could you show us the code in plunker or somewhere else?

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your answer. And is it possible to make a filter to search for an item in my table from UI-select as the "TextBox" down?.Thanks
Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/EHAFbhnLOhE6mCOBEhDH?p=preview

Comment: yes sure. I hope it will help you: http://plnkr.co/edit/L3NXUu1eoO3WYW2gJDgu?p=preview

Comment: thank you a lot.
but I also hope that the filter with the "ui-select" can work with the filter "TextBox" .Is that it is possible that the two can work together? The problem is that the filter with "ui-select" no longer works after using the filter with "TextBox".
Then it's possible to choose a default value  to nothing in the choices ?

Comment: Filter can work with anything. If you want to filter your data you need to give filter value you want match it with. So i rewrote example. Add default value and button to set empty. http://plnkr.co/edit/pVYjvK2TidOaGLo0fUO7?p=preview

Comment: Ah OK, so it's not possible to put a value like "ALL" in the "UI-select" ?. (To not use the button "CLEAR")
And about my second question, if I make a filter on the "textbox" first, the Fitre the "UI-select" no longer works after. is what is the case?
Thank you

Comment: ui select reley on your text-box. It depends on text-box's value. http://plnkr.co/edit/qVRTVvXU3iIkl2WAy4J5?p=preview

Comment: Sorry maybe my explanation is not clear.
I wish the "textBox" filter on the code and the "UI-select" filter on the name.
Exemple1 : 
<Ui-select : Afghanistan,
TextBox : AF,
-->RESULT : Afghanistan AF>
Exemple2 : 
Ui-select : Afghanistan
TextBox : AX
RESULT : None
Exemple2 : 
Ui-select : All
TextBox : ‘’
RESULT :  All items displayed


And if I'm going to choose "All" on the "UI-select" and if  empty my textBox, all the items in the list will be displayed.
Is it possible to have this working?
Thank you.
Are you are available to chat on skype 

Comment: I sent you a request skype